# Use the result of the 1st while loop in a 2nd query

Tags: php, sql

i'm executing a query and i want to use all the result in the 2nd query.
Let's say i have 3 results from the 1st query and i want to put them in the 2nd with the UNION ALL.
Can you help me please ?

```
$sql = sqlsrv_query($con,"select distinct database from Databases_2022") or die(sqlsrv_error());                
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql) )
$tsql ="select tn,
        isnull(sum(case when stat =1 then 1 else 0 end),'') as  'TEST',
        isnull(sum(case when stat in(1,4,6,7,9,10) then 1 else 0 end),'') as  'TEST2'
        from 
        (select * from RESIDENT.DBO."$row['database']". 
        union all select * from RESIDENT.DBO."$row['database']" 
        union all select * from  RESIDENT.DBO."$row['database']")a 
        group by tn
        order by tn
```

Comment: Do a JOIN instead.

Comment: My problem isn't in the union all but in "$row['database']"
How to say this is the 1st result of the array, and the "$row['database']" is the 2nd one etc ...

Comment: You need to explain by an example of what the data might be and what you want the result to be.

Comment: I want the result like this :
(select * from RESIDENT.DBO.database1 
        union all select * from RESIDENT.DBO.database2
        union all select * from  RESIDENT.DBO.database3) a